# Ruby Optional Parameters and Multiple Parameters

Tags: ruby, parameters, arguments, optional-parameters

I am trying to set the first argument to a method as being optional, followed by any number of args. For example:

```
def dothis(value=0, *args)
```

The issue I am running into is that it doesn't seem like this is actually possible? When I call `dothis("hey", "how are you", "good")` I was hoping it would set value to default to 0, but instead it is just making `value="hey"`. Is there any way to accomplish this behavior?

Comment: You passed the first argument `"hey"`, which was assigned to `value`. Hence the default value has no effect. What is wrong with it?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is retaining value=0 and being able to recognize that "hey" is the start of args, not value. This is because I am calling a function where value is 0 about 90 percent of the time. But every once in awhile, it needs to be one. This is why I was hoping to use it as a default parameter.

Comment: How would Ruby know whether the first argument you pass is supposed to be `value` or the first element of `args`? Do you think Ruby reads your mind?

Comment: 'value = 0' this is not optional argument, but default.

Comment: That was the point of the question...Whether or not there was another way to achieve this behavior or if it was impossible. I apologize for offending you..no need to be hostile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible directly in Ruby

There are plenty of options though, depending on what you are doing with your extended params, and what the method is intended to do.

Obvious choices are

1) Take named params using hash syntax

```
def dothis params
  value = params[:value] || 0
  list_of_stuff = params[:list] || []
```

Ruby has nice calling convention around this, you don't need to provide the hash {} brackets

```
dothis :list => ["hey", "how are you", "good"]
```

2) Move value to the end, and take an array for the first param

```
def dothis list_of_stuff, value=0
```

Called like this:

```
dothis ["hey", "how are you", "good"], 17
```

3) Use a code block to provide the list

```
dothis value = 0
  list_of_stuff = yield
```

Called like this

```
dothis { ["hey", "how are you", "good"] }
```

4) Ruby 2.0 introduced named hash parameters, which handle a lot of option 1, above for you:

```
def dothis value: 0, list: []
  # Local variables value and list already defined
  # and defaulted if necessary
```

Called same way as (1):

```
dothis :list => ["hey", "how are you", "good"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. @Kyle, I like your solution as well, but I'm not sure I want to bulk of naming the parameters simply because in some cases, there will be many. However, I will certainly try out both ways, and see which I would prefer. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @adback03 No problem, I like Neils' solutions better anyway ;)

Answer (score 3):

This post is a little bit old, but I want to contribute if someone is looking for the best solution for that. **Since ruby 2.0**, you can do that easily with named arguments defined with a hash. The syntax is easy and more readable.

```
def do_this(value:0, args:[])
   puts "The default value is still #{value}"
   puts "-----------Other arguments are ---------------------"
  for i in args
    puts i
  end
end
do_this(args:[ "hey", "how are you", "good"])
```

You can also do the same thing with the greedy keyword ****args** as a hash, like this:

```
#**args is a greedy keyword
def do_that(value: 0, **args)
  puts "The default value is still #{value}"
  puts '-----------Other arguments are ---------------------'
  args.each_value do |arg|
    puts arg
  end
end
do_that(arg1: "hey", arg2: "how are you", arg3: "good")
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use named parameters to accomplish this:

```
def dothis(args)
  args = {:value => 0}.merge args
end

dothis(:value => 1, :name => :foo, :age => 23)
 # => {:value=>1, :name=>:foo, :age=>23} 
dothis(:name => :foo, :age => 23)
 # => {:value=>0, :name=>:foo, :age=>23}
```

Answer (score 0):

by using value=0 you are actually assigning 0 to value. just to retain the value, you can either use the above mentioned solutions or just simply use value everytime you call this method def dothis(value, digit=[*args]).

The default arguments are used when the arguments are not provided.

I came across the similar issue and I got over it by using:

```
def check(value=0, digit= [*args])
puts "#{value}" + "#{digit}"
end
```

and simply call check like this:

```
dothis(value, [1,2,3,4])
```

your value would be default and other values belong to other argument.